# plist file not being found

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to write a simple array to a plist file and then later on retrieve it. I have the following code:

```
+ (NSString*) dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataFilePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TipAlertViewDefaults.plist"];

    return dataFilePath;
}

+ (NSArray*) tipAlertViewDefaults
{
    NSString *dataFilePath = [self dataFilePath];
    NSLog(@"DataFilePath: %@", dataFilePath);
    NSMutableArray *tipAlertViewDefaults;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataFilePath])
    {
        NSLog(@"File Exists");
        tipAlertViewDefaults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataFilePath];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"File Doesn't Exist");
        tipAlertViewDefaults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], nil];
        [tipAlertViewDefaults writeToFile:dataFilePath atomically:YES];
    }

    return tipAlertViewDefaults;
}
```

I call this method twice, in the first it should not find the file and write it for the first time. The second call then should be able to find the file but it isn't. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't"? Which branch of your `if`/`else` should be entered, and which is actually being entered? Are you getting any error messages? (Also, this is a syntax error: `return [dataFilePath];`)

Comment: `return [dataFilePath];` - this does not compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Again, Xcode's stupid autocomplete made you lost: `NSDocumentationDirectory` should really be `NSDocumentDirectory`.

The Documentation directory doesn't exist on iOS, so you can't write there.

Comment: (One more reason to start building iOS apps using `vi` and `make`?)

Comment: Checking for the file in your app's document directory would tell you it's not being written there, as well: `/users/<user name>/library/application support/iphone simulator/<iOS version>/Applications/ ... you'll have to hunt for your app by ID but you'll find it there.

Comment: Yeah this looks to be the problem. Using `NSDocumentationDirectory` returns a path, but the directory does not exist so any file access will fail unless the directory is created manually first.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to write in `NSDocumentationDirectory` directory? I think, this directory is not created by default (so you must make it before).

Perhaps you wanted `NSDocumentDirectory`. I tried it and your code works.